# Android update issue with google map API

Tags: android, google-api, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am developing an app with min sdk version 7, I already installed all the third party add-ons  available. I had all the sdk till android 3.2. The app was working perfectly with some minor issues.... that I would have fixed eventually.

The problem is I updated my SDK to Ice cream sandwich version, and after that I am unable to see anything on google map api that i used in my app. (just some white space with boxes on it)

ANY IDEA HOW TO RESOLVE THIS ISSUE?

another problem i faced is... when I gave the complete work-space to my friend for development, his android sdk showed atleast a thousand errors after importing the project... like default properties not found (the physical file). I found there is one file called project properties in android (4.0 updated) sdk and default properties in 3.2 and below. (I am taking care of the google map api key, so that is not an issue)...

Is there any procedure we need to follow to migrate android project on lower version of android ?

The sdk version of app is 7 in my as well as my friends system so ideally it should work the same and it should not throw any error on importing.

Any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: it has worked perfectly before I updated my sdk....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell your friend to Update eclipse and ADT to Indigo and ADT-16. his problem of Default Properties will be solved, and also JDK Compiler compliance
should be same.

Comment: Thanks @Praashant. I told him to update the complete sdk instead. :).